# Question studying Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney's "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

I am studying **Hirsch, Smale, Devaney; Differential equations, dynamical systems, and an introduction to chaos (2nd edition)** and have a couple of questions.

First, in Section 3.3 about repeated eigenvalues, we study

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$

The solution is basically solve the second line, getting $y(t)=\beta e^{\lambda t}$ (*). So, $x'(t)=\lambda x(t)+\beta e^{\lambda t}$ and we can use the method of
undetermined coefficients, getting $x'(t)=\alpha e^{\lambda t}+\mu t e^{\lambda t}.$

I was wondering:

> And if neither of the two lines is independent of the other? I mean, and if I cannot get (*)?

The second question is about the trace-determinant plane. The book says:

> A one-parameter family of linear systems corresponds to a curve in the TD–plane. When this curve **crosses the T-axis, the positive D-axis, or the parabola $T^2 − 4D = 0$**, the phase portrait of the linear system undergoes a bifurcation: A major change occurs in the geometry
> of the phase portrait.

However, I was wondering something like this:
[image: TD-plane with comments]

Where is my error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you think $D=0$ *isn't* a bifurcation and $\tau=0,D<0$ *is* a bifurcation?

Comment: @MatthewH., yes, I think $D=0$ no, unless if $T=0$, maybe. But $T=0, D<0$ yes...

Comment: If $D<0$ then both eigenvalues are real and have opposite signs. This is *regardless* of the values of $\tau$. The eigenspace corresponding to the positive eigenvalue will be an *unstable* manifold while the eigenspace corresponding to the *negative* eigenvalue will be a stable manifold.

Comment: If $D=0$ then any point in the eigenspace corresponding to the null eigenvalue will be a stationary point of your system, and moving from $D>0$ to $D<0$ changes the geometric structure of solution cuvres

Comment: @MatthewH. ooooh, I think I understood the diagram in a wrong manner.... The saddle is w.r.t. all of the $D<0$ semiplane, not only the $T=0, D<0$ semiaxis, right? Can you see what I've seen? Oooh, yes, now OK.... Thank you really much!!

Comment: @MatthewH. I was also thinking about my first question, and I think it's always possible to have something in form $y'=\lambda y$ because all of matrices with repeated eigenvalues can be transformed into a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&a\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$ throughout a linear transformation, I am right? Thank you!